# BOOST ASIO using

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I wanted to know how I can I make the io do something like a thread.join() wait for all tasks to finish.

```
io_type->post(  strand->wrap(boost::bind &somemethod,ptr,parameter)));
```

In the above code if 4 threads were initially launched this would give work to the next available thread. However I want to know how I could actually wait for all the threads to finish work. Like we do with `threads.join()`.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this really needs to be done, then you could setup a mutex or critical section to stop your io handlers from processing messages off of the socket.  This would need to be activated from another thread.  But, more importantly...

Perhaps you should rethink your design.  The problem with having the io wait for other threads to finish is that the io would then be unresponsive.  In general, not a good idea.  I suspect that most developers working on networking software would not even consider it.  If you are receiving messages that are not ready to be processed yet due to other processing that is going on, then consider storing them in a queue and process them on a different thread when the other threads have signaled that they have completed their work.